# Mouse pressed trigger for control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, wpf-controls

I have a control which mainly has one image(I will add more later).I have defined the template .
I want to define a trigger for mouse press but I couldn't find any in control class documentation.
Which property should I check for mouse click.

```
 <Grid>

    <Control x:key="Mycontrol" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Control.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="220"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="540"/>
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate >
                                 <Grid>
                                     <Image Source="Base.png" />                                       
                                 </Grid>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                       <Trigger Property="XXXXXXX" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                       </Trigger>
                       </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>                        

            </Style>

        </Control.Style>
    </Control>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "trap" a mouse click trigger in order to change some other properties of your control, you can use an [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation ... />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your control needs to respond to mouse click, it is always better to use Button for that purpose. IsPressed property is defined in ButtonBase, which will fullfill your need.

```
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```